# MySQL count similar rows in a select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT organisation.organisation as org, kund_nr as kundnrnr
FROM anv_data
INNER JOIN organisation ON organisation.ID = anv_data.organisation_id
INNER JOIN anvandare ON anv_data.anvandare_id = anvandare.ID
WHERE anv_data.indatum<='2013-10-31' AND anv_data.indatum>='2013-10-01' AND anv_data.rp = '0'
GROUP BY MONTH(anv_data.indatum), anv_data.anvandare_id ORDER BY anvandare.anstallningsnr
```

That generates this response:

```
organisation    kundnr
---------------------------
Företag1        123456
Företag1        123456
Företag1        123456
Företag2        789123
Företag2        789123
Företag2        789123
Företag2        789123
```

I would like to modify the query so that it sums up rows withs similar "organisation" so it looks like:

```
organisation    kundnr  sum
---------------------------
Företag1        123456  3
Företag2        789123  4
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what happens when organizations differ on kundnr in multiple occurances?

Comment: do a group by on kundnr

Comment: I tried adding that to group by, nothing changed I'm afraid.

Comment: look into the mysql soundex() and sound_like() functions : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.org,A.kundnrnr,count(1) as sum
FROM(
    SELECT organisation.organisation as org, kund_nr as kundnrnr
    FROM anv_data
    INNER JOIN organisation ON organisation.ID = anv_data.organisation_id
    INNER JOIN anvandare ON anv_data.anvandare_id = anvandare.ID
    WHERE anv_data.indatum<='2013-10-31' AND anv_data.indatum>='2013-10-01' AND anv_data.rp = '0'
    GROUP BY MONTH(anv_data.indatum), anv_data.anvandare_id ORDER BY anvandare.anstallningsnr
     ) A
GROUP BY A.org,A.kundnrnr
```

Comment: Using the above example modified to COUNT(1) gives me:

Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: I have learned that there is a big difference between `Count(*)`, `Count(table.field)` and `Count(1)`.
The best way is Count (1).

Comment: Patrik, use `Count( table.field )`, the use depends on the sentence.
table.field = primary key

Comment: Thanks for your responses, how ever it still gives me "Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias" when I tried that.

Comment: Hi rshetye, I tried it and it gave me a "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'A.kund_nr' in 'field list'"

Comment: That did produce a correct sum column, Thank you so much for helping, this has puzzled me for days.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 SELECT organisation.organisation as org, kund_nr as kundnrnr, COUNT(*) sum
 FROM anv_data
 INNER JOIN organisation ON organisation.ID = anv_data.organisation_id
 INNER JOIN anvandare ON anv_data.anvandare_id = anvandare.ID
 WHERE anv_data.indatum<='2013-10-31' AND anv_data.indatum>='2013-10-01' AND anv_data.rp = '0'
 GROUP BY organisation.organisation, kund_nr
 ORDER BY organisation.organisation
```

Comment: It did produce a sum row but the count was way too high (514 and 65) I wonder if it did sum all instead of the month specified in the WHERE statement